# How can I use Google Chrome's V8 JavaScript interpreter from Delphi?

Tags: javascript, delphi

I'd like to embed the V8 JavaScript interpreter that ships with Google Chrome within my Delphi application. I'm aware of the [chromium embedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/downloads/list) open-source project from Google, but I'd like to know if anyone was aware of any Pascal/Delphi wrappers?

There is an example project included with the zip file on the site I linked, which is written in C++. If nothing else, I'll slowly and painfully work to convert it.

**UPDATE**:
I just want to embed the V8 JavaScript interpreter, *not* the Chromium browser.

Comment: Do you want to embed the Chronium browser or just the V8 javascript engine?

Comment: I just want to embed the V8 JavaScript engine...not the browser.

Comment: One year later: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record: hgourvest has posted [Delphi Chromium Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) to Google Code.

Edit 2013-01-15:

Another project by the same author this time wrapping CEF3: [DCEF3](http://code.google.com/p/dcef3/)

Answer (score 3):

The most ideal solution would be to create a wrapper, preferably which consumes the original source unmodified, and compile that wrapper to an OBJ file (using C++) which then is linked into Delphi, where another "wrapper" exposes the engine via a more standard object pascal syntax.  This approach would then allow for changes in the engine without the need for a complete conversion each time new functionality or additional performance is added.  The only disadvantage of this approach is that there will be some performance lost while navigating the layers...but I would expect it to be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

If it is in fact Chrome as a browser you want to embed into your application, you should check out [Google Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/), it exposes COM interfaces, primarily to integrate into Internet Explorer, but in theory we should be able to access them also.

(I'm not sure because I would like to have a go at this myself, but it's on a (long) list of really neat things to try when I get around to them.)
**Update**: I've had a quick go at it, got a "No interface supported" error, and posted it [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36639).

Comment: I think he is talking about the V8 interpreter not about the chrome frame. V8 can be used independly in any application, but we need a wrapper for Delphi.

Comment: Francis: I was really hoping he is talking about the V8 interpreter, and also that someone posts a better answer than mine... Does anyone know japanese? http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=V8+iactivescriptsite&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Comment: I am referring to the V8 interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

- If you're using Prism, read this: http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/ck/2010/02/23/p1175. 
  RemObjects made a free and open [source](http://code.remobjects.com/p/roscript/source/tree/HEAD/trunk/Source/RemObjects.Script) scripting engine that supports ECMA Script (JavaScript) and PascalScript.  It's all pascal code, but it depends on DotNet (RemObjects wrote it in Prism of course).
- There's a [V8 wrapper for Python](http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/PyV8-Download-51051.html). Might be interesting to see how they pulled it off.
- There's a V8 Swig script here, but getting Swig to work with Delphi might be a challenge on its own: http://v8.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=7578402775385555895&name=jav8.i
- You can use the JavaScript engine from FireFox from within your Delphi application with [Delphi / Kylix <-> SpiderMonkey Bridge](http://delphi.mozdev.org/javascript_bridge/)

Comment: Good info! I considered the SpiderMonkey Bridge (Malzilla uses it), but it is a few years old and I want something that'll work with the new unicode enabled versions of Delphi (2009 and 2010).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the SpiderMonkey bridge also, without any problems. Runs reasonably fast, without a huge footprint, and have had no Unicode issues yet!

Answer (score 1):

Start from Jun 1, 2016, we have [v8delphiwrapper](https://github.com/zolagiggszhou/v8delphiwrapper), kudos to the developer @zolagiggszhou. And I'd like to show you some code example:

## Run js code and return result as `string`:

```
Memo2.Text := FEngine.eval(Memo1.Text);
```

## Accessing Delphi object from js:

1 - Assuming you have a Delphi class like this:

```
  TJsAccessableClass = class
  public
    function add(a,b: Double): Double;
    function httpEncode(const s: string): string;
  end;
```

2 - You register it with the v8 js engine:

```
  FObjectTemplate2 := FEngine.RegisterRttiClass(TJsAccessableClass);
  FJsAccessableObject := FObjectTemplate2.CreateInstance(TJsAccessableClass.Create);
  Fv8GlobalObject.SetObject('delphiObj', FJsAccessableObject);
```

3 - Now you can **call your Delphi method from js**:

```
var s = delphiObj.httpEncode('/~!f234');
```

Very cool! More example please check [v8delphiwrapper sample project](https://github.com/zolagiggszhou/v8delphiwrapper/blob/master/demo/Unit1.pas)