# Javascript Engine for Delphi

Tags: javascript, delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

Are there any out there that work with 64 bits? So I can use it along IdHTPP.

**Edit:** I found SpiderMonkey for Delphi. It supports 64 bit but there is no 64 bit dll provided. "js64.dll" that is.

http://code.google.com/p/delphi-javascript/

**Here is the 64 bit build. It works perfect with delphi-javascript**

http://depositfiles.com/files/tfryg81ny

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/ ?

Comment: It doesn't provide js64.dll, but it doesn't provide js32.dll, either. I think you're supposed to get that from Mozilla (or compile it yourself from Mozilla's code).

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve, but I found this recently and from what I have done with it so far it works great.  Since Active Script is COM based I guess it doesn't matter about the 32/64 bit issue.  I am only on D2010 and don't have 64-bit though.

http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/generic-idispatch-proxies-for-active-scripting/

Comment: @RobKennedy It does provide js32.dll http://code.google.com/p/delphi-javascript/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdemo 

Thats to bad that support is for 64 bit but no 64 bit dll..

Comment: @RobKennedy Yep it must be compiled probably. Would be too hard i think.

Comment: The combination of requiring both >4GB and JavaScript makes me cringe.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick 64 bit is the future.

Comment: @RichardO'Reilly: 32bits applications (Delphi, Visual Studio, Chrome, etc)  are not about to disappear any time soon. In general I'd say that if your application requires more than 2GB of RAM per instance it's a red flag that you're probably doing something wrong. There are exceptions of course, but at this point in time, they are rare.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick I am devloping a data mining application :)

Comment: How about this one: http://code.google.com/p/besen/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about TWebBrowser?

Create 64bits Delphi application, drop a TWebBrowser on your form, and run this:

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.ParentWindow.execScript('alert("Hello")');
```

Voila, no extra components needed.

---

[image: In Action]

Comment: Yes i was thinking of using this and outputing the results to a 64 bit MySQL so i am not limited by memory there.

Comment: By the way, run this to see that it's actually the 64bits engine: `WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.ParentWindow.execScript('alert(navigator.userAgent)');`. When you compile to 32bits, this won't show the x64 part.

Comment: Problem with IE is its a wrapper. It can't be threaded well very hard. Chrome Embedded would be better to use..

Comment: @RichardO'Reilly: yeah that might be better, but it doesn't exist today. Read this: http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/64-bit-support

Comment: So it can be compiled as 64 bit :) ?

Comment: Yes, but not for windows. I sure hope you're not planning to do your >4GB multi-threaded datamining app with JavaScript and Delphi for MacOSX!

Comment: With all due respect, Besen should be the correct answere here if you are looking for a Delphi native version, followed by V8 and Spidermonkey. TWebbrowser can hardly be called a browser, it breaks every standard in the book on a whim; Let alone a "javascript engine" as the question entails.

Besen is a Javascript engine. V8 is a Javascript engine - spidermonkey is a Javascript engine. This is like asking "what is a car" and being shown a moped. Not the same thing.

Comment: @jonlennartaasenden: Besen is a super cool project, but to somebody who doesn't even know how to call JavaScript from a Delphi application it's probably not really the best advice to use Besen. Last time I've tried it, I couldn't get any framework to work with it. If you have problems with the modern Internet Explorer for not complying to standards, I wonder why you suggest Besen. If you know what you're doing: try Besen to get a full Delphi solution; otherwise, better stick to a more standard solution, I'd advise.

Answer (score 10):

You can try also [BESEN](http://code.google.com/p/besen/) which is a ECMAScript/JavaScript Engine written in ObjectPascal itself, without any external DLL libraries.

Comment: Late reaction, but BESEN is an amazing piece of code. I'm even more amazed that one single person has been able to make something of this complexity work at all. Respect!

Answer (score 3):

The mORMot ORM framework has a [JavaScript Engine](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1044&p=7) based on SpiderMonkey 45, which means it supports ES2015.

BTW, it also has a Node.js-compatible server-side JS implementation, very cool.

---

Apr 7, 2017 update: Now the SyNode JS engine included in mORMot is based on **SpiderMonkey 52**. github commit is [here](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/commit/75aa35495a28328a65fcbd1bb28b6d5d925c9ab2).

Answer (score 0):

There is new Delphi wrapper for Google's V8 JS engine, available since Jun 1, 2016, called [v8delphiwrapper](https://github.com/zolagiggszhou/v8delphiwrapper)

See [some example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47218541/133516) I demonstrated here.

Great thanks to it's developer @zolagiggszhou!